# quering whether a key exist in mysql or not from servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

Its a simple question and may have many answers. Please tell me the fastest method to do that as my database is too large.
I want to make a simple call from servlet to mysql asking about whether a particular key(primary in my case) exists in database. If it exists it should return true,let say, or false otherwise.

WHAT is the fastest method to do that and if your answer is to implement SELECT * from x where...  ,, then please tell me how to check when resultset is empty. is it null or what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT * from ...";
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryCheck); // execute the query, and get a java resultset

            if(rs.absolute(1)) {
                //record already exist
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from x where key = something
```

It will return a integer value.

if value >0 = true. Else false.